# iOS selecting pictures from photo library programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got a question. Is there possiblity to select from code a given set of pictures from iOS device photos library? I don't want to use UIImagePickerController because I want to decide for user which pictures I want to refer to in my application.

Didn't find anything viable because all questions are about or related to UIImagePickerController.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints for you
You can use The Assets Library Framework. Read the documentation: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/AssetsLibraryFramework/_index.html

Or you can use some of the code from: http://www.fiveminutes.eu/accessing-photo-library-using-assets-library-framework-on-iphone/